# Spring Boot mismatch version/build path

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a Spring project with my team for my bootcamp capstone and we've been running into an issue with build paths differing between branches. I believe this has to do with the recent update to Spring Boot (3.1.4) when most of the project was written on 3.1.3. We can get around this using the Language supporter from Red Hat (It'll throw a message when we try to change branches, saying 'build path has changed, would you like to synchronize classpath?' or something similar) but we're concerned that when we start to merge our branches back to main that everything will break.

Whenever we tried to swap between 3.1.3 and 3.1.4 in the pom.xml, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.